# Is it possible to get last tokens in a string line without using string.split?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to split a given string without using string.spliit but using the code below, I can only get the first token 'abc' but I also want to get 'jkl'. How can I do that? Because it's my homework, I don't want the code itself but the logic behind it. Thank you in advance.

Note: I am not allowed to use tuples, lists, dictionaries etc.

```
is_begin = True
def get_field(line):

    t_ind = line.find('\t')
  
    if is_begin ==True:
        return line[0:t_ind]
    else:
        return (line[t_ind:-1])
    return line

letters = "abc\tdef\tghi\tjkl"
print(get_field(letters))
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: The expected outputs are for the first token "abc", for the last token "jkl"

Comment: so you need to get abc, def, ghi, and jkl.. not the first and the last right?

Comment: I want only get "abc" and "jkl" seperately. Can I do that by adding two positional arguments ?

Comment: yes by adding a second positional argument you could do that

Answer (score 1):

Find the first and last position of occurrence of '\t' in the `letters` according to the second argument.

If the second argument is `True` find the first occurrence and take out the first token by index values. Here, when `is_begin == True` find the index of the first occurrence and take out the string by `line[0:t_ind]` where `t_ind` is the index of the first occurrence. 0 means from the start of the string and t_ind means the end of the first token.

Likewise, when `is_begin != True` find the index of the last occurrence and take out the last token by `line[t_ind+1:]` where `t_ind` is the index of the last occurrence. But here, we need to add 1 to t_ind so that we can start from the starting of the last token just after after `\t`. The end index has not been given to `line[t_ind+1:]` since we need to get the last token to the last character. Hope this makes sense.

You could do this with two positional arguments and by using

> `find()` method finds the first occurrence of the specified value.

and

> `rfind()` method finds the last occurrence of the specified value.

```
def get_field(line, is_begin):
  if is_begin == True:
    t_ind = line.find('\t')
    return line[0:t_ind]
  else:
    t_ind = line.rfind('\t')
    return line[t_ind+1:]

letters = "abc\tdef\tghi\tjkl"

print(get_field(letters, True))
print(get_field(letters, False))
```

output:

```
abc
jkl
```

Comment: **I don't want the code itself but the logic behind it**

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `abc` and `jkl`, try experimenting with `find` and `rfind`.

Comment: Actually, it's not specifically "abc" or "jkl". It was just an example to express what I want. This code is just a part of a whole code and the remaining of it will work according to that code.

Comment: _I want only get "abc" and "jkl" seperately._ You mentioned this on your comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved by using iterator.

```py
def get_field(line):

    while True:
        t_ind = line.find('\t')
        if t_ind == -1:
            yield line
            break
        field = line[0:t_ind]
        line = line[t_ind+1:]
        yield field

letters = "abc\tdef\tghi\tjkl"
for field in get_field(letters):
    print(field)
```

Comment: **I don't want the code itself but the logic behind it**